# Bitmap is null when being observed two times by Live Data

Tags: android, retrofit

I have `ImageView imgProfil` in `MojProfilActivity` and I want to load a picture from a database there. It works just fine the first time, but after I try it the second time the `bmp` is null for some strange reason. Can you help, please?

```
MutableLiveData<ResponseBody> mld = UserRepository.getInstance(MainApplication.apiManager).GetProfilna(Utils.getInstance().getKorisnik().getId());
            mld.observe(MojProfilActivity.this, new Observer<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(ResponseBody responseBody) {
                    bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(responseBody.byteStream());
                    imgProfil.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
            });
```

This is my interface:

```
public interface RestInterface {
    @GET("users/getprofilna/{UserId}")
    Call<ResponseBody> GetProfilna(@Path("UserId") String UserId);
}
```

This is my Api Manager

```
public class ApiManager {
    private static RestInterface service;
    private static ApiManager apiManager;

    private ApiManager(){
        service = RetrofitService.Create();
    }
    public static ApiManager getInstance(){
        if(apiManager == null) {
            apiManager = new ApiManager();
        }
        return  apiManager;
    }
    public void GetProfilna(String UserId, Callback<ResponseBody> callback){
        Call<ResponseBody> getProfilna = service.GetProfilna(UserId);
        getProfilna.enqueue(callback);
    }
}
```

This is my UserRespository class:

```
public class UserRepository {
    private static volatile UserRepository instance;
    private final ApiManager apiManager;

    private final MutableLiveData<ResponseBody> responseBody = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private UserRepository(ApiManager apiManager){
        this.apiManager = apiManager;
    }

    public static UserRepository getInstance(ApiManager apiManager){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new UserRepository(apiManager);
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public MutableLiveData<ResponseBody> GetProfilna(String UserId){
        apiManager.GetProfilna(UserId, new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    responseBody.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });

        return responseBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: once the `ResponseBody::byteStream` is consumed once it cannot be reused.  A better solution is to convert to a Bitmap and store in the `UserRepository` which is also more efficient as you do the computation once as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We can't send Bitmap from the database, is there some other way? To convert responseBody from UserRespository we'll have to use byteStream again.

Comment: "We can't send Bitmap from the database" - I didn't mention a database? I stated `UserRepository` which is not a database, just an in memory abstraction around a `MutableLiveData<ResponseBody>` object. Just convert the response body to a bitmap in the callback `onResponse` (shift the logic out of the UI - it doesn't belong there) and set that value on the live data so you end up with `MutableLiveData<Bitmap>`.